# `as.na` function

Tags: r

In R, almost every `is.*` function I can think of has a corresponding `as.*`. There is a `is.na` but no `as.na`. Why not and how would you implement one if such function makes sense?

I have a vector `x` that can be `logical`, `character`, `integer`, `numeric`  or `complex` and I want to convert it to a vector of same class and length, but filled with the appropriate: `NA`, `NA_character_`, `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, or `NA_complex_`.

My current version:

```
as.na <- function(x) {x[] <- NA; x}
```

Comment: Something like: `sapply(x,function(x) x <- NA)` might work.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, no your suggestion returns a `logical` no matter what the input.

Comment: Thank you for the answers so far. Anyone have an idea why the function does not exist in the first place?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not use `is.na<-` as directed in `?is.na`?

```
> l <- list(integer(10), numeric(10), character(10), logical(10), complex(10))
> str(lapply(l, function(x) {is.na(x) <- seq_along(x); x}))
List of 5
 $ : int [1:10] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 $ : num [1:10] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 $ : chr [1:10] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:10] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : cplx [1:10] NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: Interesting, but this is actually runs a bit **slower** than the OP's function.

Comment: Sure, but `is.na<-` is generic and methods can be written for it; I'm not sure how your or the OP's solution would handle other classes. I was thinking of robustness before speed.

Answer (score 13):

This seems to be consistently faster than your function:

```
as.na <- function(x) {
    rep(c(x[0], NA), length(x))
}
```

(Thanks to Joshua Ulrich for pointing out that my earlier version didn't preserve class attributes.)

---

Here, for the record, are some relative timings:

```
library(rbenchmark)

## The functions
flodel <- function(x) {x[] <- NA; x}
joshU <- function(x) {is.na(x) <- seq_along(x); x}
joshO <- function(x) rep(c(x[0], NA), length(x))

## Some vectors to  test them on
int  <- 1:1e6
char <- rep(letters[1:10], 1e5)
bool <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5e5)

benchmark(replications=100, order="relative",
    flodel_bool = flodel(bool),
    flodel_int  = flodel(int),
    flodel_char = flodel(char),
    joshU_bool = joshU(bool),
    joshU_int  = joshU(int),
    joshU_char = joshU(char),
    joshO_bool = joshO(bool),
    joshO_int  = joshO(int),
    joshO_char = joshO(char))[1:6]        
#          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
# 7  joshO_bool          100    0.46    1.000      0.33     0.14
# 8   joshO_int          100    0.49    1.065      0.31     0.18
# 9  joshO_char          100    1.13    2.457      0.97     0.16
# 1 flodel_bool          100    2.31    5.022      2.01     0.30
# 2  flodel_int          100    2.31    5.022      2.00     0.31
# 3 flodel_char          100    2.64    5.739      2.36     0.28
# 4  joshU_bool          100    3.78    8.217      3.13     0.66
# 5   joshU_int          100    3.95    8.587      3.30     0.64
# 6  joshU_char          100    4.22    9.174      3.70     0.51
```

Answer (score 11):

The function does not exist because it's not a type conversion.  A type conversion would be changing 1L to 1.0, or changing "1" to 1L.  The NA type isn't a conversion from another type unless that type was text.  Given that there's only one type you could possibly convert from and there are so many options for doing an assignment of NA (as in the many other answers) there's no need for such a function.

Every one of the answers you've gotten would just assign NA to everything passed in to it but you'd probably only want to do it conditionally.  Doing the assignment conditionally or calling a small wrapper would be no different.

Comment: I came to this thread because I was thinking of storing outliers as ``Inf`` and thought an ``as.na(Inf)`` might be helpful if the time came to treat these like any other missing values. My main purpose in using ``Inf`` was to distinguish outliers from other ``NA``s while at the same time not coercing a change of type from numeric to character (say). Not a good approach to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but, how about

```
as.na <- function(obj){
  if(is.factor(obj)){
    # Special case for factors - any others that need to be handled?
    factor(rep(NA, length(obj)), levels = levels(obj))
  } else{
    objClass <- class(obj)
    x <- rep(NA, length(obj))
    class(x) <- objClass 
    x
  }
}
```

For dataframes:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  int = seq(1, 10),
  real = seq(1, 10) + 0.1,
  char = letters[1:10],
  logi = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5),
  Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2019-09-03"), by = 1, length.out = 10),
  posix = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2019-09-03 12:00:00"), by = 360, length.out = 10),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) 
DF$factr <- as.factor(LETTERS[1:10])
str(DF)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ int  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ real : num  1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1 6.1 7.1 8.1 9.1 10.1
 $ char : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ logi : logi  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
 $ Date : Date, format: "2019-09-03" "2019-09-04" "2019-09-05" ...
 $ posix: POSIXct, format: "2019-09-03 12:00:00" "2019-09-03 12:06:00" "2019-09-03 12:12:00" ...
 $ factr: Factor w/ 10 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

DF_na <- DF
for(i in colnames(DF_na)){
  DF_na[,i] <- as.na(DF_na[,i])
}

str(DF_na)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ int  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 $ real : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 $ char : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ logi : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Date : Date, format: NA NA NA ...
 $ posix: POSIXct, format: NA NA NA ...
 $ factr: Factor w/ 10 levels "A","B","C","D",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

For data.tables:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table::data.table(
  int = seq(1, 10),
  real = seq(1, 10) + 0.1,
  char = letters[1:10],
  logi = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5),
  Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2019-09-03"), by = 1, length.out = 10),
  posix = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2019-09-03 12:00:00"), by = 360, length.out = 10),
  factr = as.factor(LETTERS[1:10])
)
str(DT)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ int  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ real : num  1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1 6.1 7.1 8.1 9.1 10.1
 $ char : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ logi : logi  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
 $ Date : Date, format: "2019-09-03" "2019-09-04" "2019-09-05" ...
 $ posix: POSIXct, format: "2019-09-03 12:00:00" "2019-09-03 12:06:00" "2019-09-03 12:12:00" ...
 $ factr: Factor w/ 10 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

DT_na <-
  copy(DT)[, lapply(.SD, as.na)]
str(DT_na)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ int  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 $ real : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 $ char : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ logi : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Date : Date, format: NA NA NA ...
 $ posix: POSIXct, format: NA NA NA ...
 $ factr: Factor w/ 10 levels "A","B","C","D",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```