# Init vector with NA value of same data type as another vector

Tags: r, na

I am programming a framework and try to implement a generic init function.

Given a vector v1 of a specific data type:

How can I explicitly initialize another vector v2 with NA values of the same data type as in the first vector v1?

Example:

```
v1 <- c("a", "b")
v2 <- rep(NA, length(v1))  # would use the wrong type since NA is NA_logical_ by default
typeof(v2) # "logcial"

v2 <- rep(NA_character_)   # what I really want
typeof(v2) # "character"

v1 <- 1:2
v2 <- rep(NA_real_, length(v1))
typeof(v2) "double"

# ... same for NA_complex_, NA_integer_ ...
```

Do I really have to write a function and do "if typeof(v1) then NA..."
or is there an existing function or more clever way of doing this?

Comment: After `v2 <- rep(NA, length(v1))` just do `class(v2) <- class(v1)`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I wanted to avoid overwriting the wrongly initialized vector a second time for performance reasons... Sorry for modifying the question...

Comment: I guess `v2 <- v1[v1==NA]` does it in one line. Can't speak to its performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The answers to this question might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937345/as-na-function)

A possible solution suggested from @Josh O'Brien :

```
rep(c(v1[0], NA), length(v1))
```

Comment: looks like my question being a duplicate ;-)

Comment: This is still the fastest execution regarding the first time execution (which is my primary use case) so I opt for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could make your own function. You have to type everything out, but only have to do it once.

```
na_maker <- function(class){
  switch(class,
         double = NA_real_,
         integer = NA_integer_,
         character = NA_character_,
         logical = NA,
         complex = NA_complex_)
}


v1 <- c("a", "b")
v2 <- rep(na_maker(class(v1)), length(v1))

class(v2)
[1] "character"
```

---

You could also make another wrapper function to simplify things:

```
rep_na <- function(vec){
  rep(na_maker(class(vec)), length(vec))
}

v2 <- rep_na(v1)
```

Comment: Yes, this will work in simple examples, but I cannot know each existing class of R beforehand and `class` may return a character vector of multiple class names indeed.

Comment: @RYoda you could check if any of the classes are in the listed ones. It probably should not be the case that the vector has both `numeric` and `character` for example

Answer (score 1):

My first thought (nixed by your comment) was a straightforward:

```
v2 <- rep(NA, length(v1))
class(v2) <- class(v1)
```

A one-liner would be:

```
v2 <- v1[v1==NA]
```

But this appears to be slower, e.g.:

```
library(microbenchmark)                                                 
v1 <- sample(1:10000)                                                   

microbenchmark(                                                         
one = { v2 <- v1[v1==NA] },                                             
two = { v2 <- rep(NA, length(v1)); class(v1) <- class(v2)}, times = 1000
)                                                                       
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#>   one 69.804 71.078 92.79524 71.6385 72.4335 650.255  1000
#>   two 18.983 19.424 22.96938 20.9525 21.5040 953.085  1000
```

Comment: clever approach, I am just trying to optimize it by taking only the first element of v1 to determine the required NA type...